# aws (pip) returns invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I am trying to install Amazon Web Services in pip, with

```
pip3 install awscli
```

but I am getting an error when I try to run aws or aws configure in that case:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 7, in <module>
    from aws.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aws/main.py", line 23
    print '%(name)s: %(endpoint)s' % {
```

any clues?

Comment: N.B.: this question started out with `pip3 install aws` instead of `pip3 install awscli`

Answer (score 44):

I had the same issue with python 3.6.

This is actually a different package, confusingly named "aws" which is throwing the error: https://github.com/eofs/aws

**Make sure you run**

```
pip install awscli
```

NOT pip install aws

To find out which "aws" package you are calling run:

```
 which aws
```

Comment: I made the same mistake. The problem was solved by running `pip install awscli` after `pip uninstall aws`.

Answer (score 0):

AWS package is for Python 2 only.

Comment: Nop?

[CLI INSTALL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html)

Comment: Nope. You gave me a link to `awscli` package, not `aws`. If you want helpful answers, write helpful questions.

Comment: Would you like to give me a link to the "aws" package you mean?

Comment: @wizofe on the page you linked it shows the command `pip3 install awscli` not `pip3 install aws`

Comment: @MarkB can you show me please a reference that identifies the difference between aws and awscli? I don't understand/see any difference.

Comment: @wizofe, `pip show aws`. And you will get [this link](https://github.com/eofs/aws).

Answer (score 0):

I found going into my python directory and removing the `aws.exe` fixed this error for me.

Go to this location
`C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\`

and delete this file `aws.exe`